# How can I screenshot a custom URL page and send it back into the channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, puppeteer

I am trying to make a screenshot using puppeteer and send it back into the channel where the command was typed. Anyways I can't do it, so please help me.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const client = new Discord.Client();


module.exports =  {


  async run(client, message, args) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const url = message.client;
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    
    console.log(await page.content());
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

    let screenshot = await page.screenshot(); 
    await browser.close();

    message.channel.send("Screenshot", {files: [screenshot]});
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may have made a typo.

```js
const url = message.client;
```

should probably be

```js
const url = message.content; // or something similar?
```

[`message.client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) is a [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object, and even as a string, is `[object Object]`. These are not valid URLs.

As a result, an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` should have been logged to the console, stating that the URL could not be deserialized.

You should validate the URL or catch errors in your command in the case of invalid URLs.